# Yesod fails to install (namely the text package)

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I'm trying to install Yesod via cabal, but it keeps failing on installing Data.Text.

I tried installing text separately with `cabal install text`, resulting in an error message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring text-0.11.1.0...
Preprocessing library text-0.11.1.0...
Building text-0.11.1.0...

Data/Text/Lazy/Builder/RealFloat.hs:21:7:
    Could not find module `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.RealFloat.Functions':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
text-0.11.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Investigating the directory structure of the text package that was downloaded, I find that there really is no `Data/Text/Lazy/Builder/RealFloat/Functions.hs`.  The closest thing is `Data/Text/Lazy/Builder/Functions.hs` (but this doesn't contain the function `RealFloat.hs` was trying to import, which was `roundTo`).

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like the version of `text` Yesod used at time of writing was not 0.11.1.0. Try downloading the package and changing the `import` statements manually, then install from the disk. I already had to do that (not with Yesod, though), and it worked. Hope it's as simple as that in your case.

Comment: I tried installing `text` independently, and it still doesn't work, and, after poking around the troublesome modules in the `text` package that was downloaded, I don't see any way to reasonably change the files.  I tried downloading the package from Hackage, but the same problem exists.  The problem seems to be with the `text` package's code somehow; I don't see how it could work in any situation.

Comment: This is weird, the import is for a function called "roundTo" from "Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.RealFloat.Functions" module.. but this module doesn't event exist. Also the module "Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.Functions"  doesn't have this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a ghc7.0 related issue (and listed at [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.1.0) under "Build failure"). Try to install text-0.11.0.8 that should work for yesod.

Comment: Thank you, this worked to install text.  Later, file-embed-0.0.4 also failed, but I was able to install it manually and trick cabal into thinking 0.0.4 was installed when 0.0.3 actually was, and, amazingly, it worked!

Comment: It's now [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/bos/text/issue/6/cabal-install-text-fails) in text-0.11.1.1.